# How to have SED remove all characters between a hypen and the file extension

Tags: sed

I have been trying with no luck to change this

```
'Simple' week 1-117067638.mp3
```

into this

```
'Simple' week 1.mp3
```

However when I use the command `sed 's/\(-\).*\(.mp3\)//'` I get

```
'Simple' week 1
```

How do I keep my file extension? If you could explain the command you use it would be great so that I can learn from this instead of just getting an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to have a capturing group.

```
$ echo "'Simple' week 1-117067638.mp3" | sed 's/-.*\.mp3/.mp3/g'
'Simple' week 1.mp3
```

OR

```
$ echo "'Simple' week 1-117067638.mp3" | sed 's/-.*\(\.mp3\)/\1/g'
'Simple' week 1.mp3
```

What's wrong with your code?

```
sed 's/\(-\).*\(.mp3\)//'
```

sed would replace all the matched characters with the characters in the replacement part. So `\(-\).*\(.mp3\)` matches all the characters from `-` to `.mp3` (*you must need to escape the dot in-order to match a literal dot*). You're replacing all the matched characters with an empty string. So `.mp3` also got removed. In-order to avoid this, add `.mp3` to the replacement part.
 In basic sed, capturing groups are represented by `\(..\)`. This capturing group is used to capture characters which are to be referenced later.

Comment: That works great. Can you explain your code I am still pretty new to SED?

Comment: added some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This task can also be done just in `bash` without calling `sed`:

```
$ fname="'Simple' week 1-117067638.mp3"
$ fname="${fname/-*/}.mp3"
$ echo "$fname"
'Simple' week 1.mp3
```